# PropelException [ 0 ]: Cannot determine the column to bind to the parameter in clause

Tags: propel

I get exactly this error:

```
PropelException [ 0 ]: Cannot determine the column to bind to the parameter in clause
```

This is the code I'm trying to run:

```
$myObject = MyObjectQuery::create()
    ->where('MyObject.another_object_id = ?', $foreignKey)
    ->find();
```

Is also tried this code, which gave me the very same exception

```
$myObject = MyObjectQuery::create()
    ->where('MyObject.anotherObjectId = ?', $foreignKey)
    ->find()
```

My MySQL Database Table is called "my_object" and has a foreignkey named "another_object_id". What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try :

```
$myObject = MyObjectQuery::create()
    ->where('anotherObjectId = ?', $foreignKey)
    ->find();
```

or

```
$myObject = MyObjectQuery::create()
    ->filterByAnotherObjectId($foreignKey)
    ->find();
```